# How should I manage users who loggged in through OAuth?

Tags: php, codeigniter, user-controls, oauth

Consider I have a user table which gets user data.
I have 2 cases where people can register for my site.

case 1. 
People just type every information needed to register my site. (old classic way)

case 2.
I set up OAuth where people can use Twitter or other Authentication system (providing OAuth API) to log on to my site. So, these users won't actually type in their

In what way should I store users who login through case 2 in my site? 
Do I just store their information ( that I would fetch using OAuth API) as their user ID, and tokens as their password?
Or do I have to make them register once again with provided information?

What would be the best way to manage case 1 and case 2? Can someone tell me their own experience with this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way we did it on our site is to separate the idea of a `User` and their `Authentication`. A user can have any number of Authentications, stored in a separate table. They can use *any one* of their associated authentications to log in. So we might have the following:

```
User:
  id: 1
  username: brandon_tilley
Authentication:
  id: 1
  user_id: 1
  type: password
  data: {"password": "super-secret"}
Authentication:
  id: 2
  user_id: 1
  type: oauth2
  data: {"token": "0123456789abcdef", "oauth_id": "543210"}
```

Now, when someone tries to log in to your site with a username and password, you can look up the appropriate `Authentication` record with a type of `password` and the `user_id` that matches the username; if instead someone tries to log in via OAuth2, you can see if there is an `Authentication` with the associated `token` and `oauth_id` in the database, and if so, log in the associated User.

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting Q & A and something I've been thinking about myself as it's the next upgrade I want to do on my CMS.

So I understand what you're saying:

When someone tries to login:

Check their username against the "users" table, then check the type of authentication they use in the "authentications" table.

If it's just a stored password, they just have a regular account - log them in.

If they've been stored using OAuth etc, tr using the stored info to log them in remotely to their service of choice - if successful, log them in.